# How i can get a value that is inside a map, inside other map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm newbie in golang and I have this problem.

```
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    func main() {
    
        Problem := map[string]interface{}{
            "Alan": map[string]interface{}{
                "Particulars": map[string]interface{}{
                    "Age": "28",
                },
            },
            "Sophia": map[string]interface{}{
                "Particulars": map[string]interface{}{
                    "Age": "18",
                 },
            },
        }

    Ages := []string{}
    for key, value := range Problem {
        fmt.Println(key)
        fmt.Println(value)
        Ages = value["Age"]
    }
}
```

I want to use the valor of "Age" for something, how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value in interface{} type can be any type of value. Use a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to ensure the value type is valid for the operation before accessing it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    Problem := map[string]interface{}{
        "Alan": map[string]interface{}{
            "Particulars": map[string]interface{}{
                "Age": "28",
            },
        },
        "Sophia": map[string]interface{}{
            "Particulars": map[string]interface{}{
                "Age": "18",
            },
        },
    }

    Ages := []string{}
    for key, value := range Problem {
        fmt.Println(key)
        fmt.Println(value)
        a, ok := value.(map[string]interface{})["Particulars"].(map[string]interface{})["Age"].(string)
        if ok {
            Ages = append(Ages, a)
        }

    }
    fmt.Println(Ages)

}
```